# duplicate thread made by onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, multithreading, duplicates

i have a button with onclicklistener that download a picture from internet and update progress-bar in UI thread . when users click on the button for first time , it work correctly , but if the users click on the button for seconds &... when download is not completed , a duplicate process happens  .how could i get rid of this problem?

```
    Button btnDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndownload);
    final TextView txtcaption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtcaption);
    final ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                OnProgressDownloadListener listener = new OnProgressDownloadListener() {

                       @Override
                          public void progressDownload(final int percent) {
                         new HANDLER.post(new Runnable() {

                              @Override
                               public void run() {
                               progress.setProgress(percent);
                               txtcaption.setText(percent + " %");
                               if (percent >= 100) {

                                  txtcaption.setText("completed");
                                  Toast.makeText(activity.this, "download completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                  }
                            });
                        }
                  };

                @Override
                public void run() {
       //my download manager                                
                    FileDownloader.download("address/file", DIR + "/file");
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Disable the button once you start downloading or set a flag when you have initiated download.

Comment: What makes this not "good enough?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be the following...

First, begin by declaring a thread...
`Thread myThread`

Then create a simple method that contains the thread you wish to execute when the button is pressed...

```
private void getPicture()
    {
        myThread = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                // Place thread code here...
            }
        };
        myThread.start();
    }
```

Then you can do a simple check when the button is pressed and, if the thread is active, don't call the `getPicture` method...buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

```
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (myThread.isAlive())
        {
            // Thread is alive, do not launch again
        }
        else
        {
            // Thread is not running so call method...
            getPicture();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a Thread variable in your class that's initialized to NULL.  In your onClickListener, check the value of that variable.  If its null, start a new thread and save the value of that thread in the variable.  If it isn't, ignore the button press or pop up a downloading toast.  Remember to set the variable back to null when your thread is completed.

I'd highly recommend using an AsyncTask for this rather than a thread, it will be cleaner.